# problem with reading connection string in tests c#

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, connection-string, app-config

I have this code

```
[TestMethod]
public void test_repository_usage()
{
    RepositoryTestClass repositoryTest = new RepositoryTestClass();

    IEnumerable<PartOfSpeech> partOfSpeech = repositoryTest.GetPartOfSpeech();

    Assert.IsTrue(partOfSpeech != null);
}
```

This is my context file

```
public class GlosolaliaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PlWord> PlWords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EnWord> EnWords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PartOfSpeech> PartsOfSpeech { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings settings =
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GlosolaliaDB"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            settings.ConnectionString
            );
}
```

And in `app.config` in my test project, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="GlosolaliaDB"
             connectionString="server = 127.0.0.1,1433; Database = Glosolalia; Trusted_Connection = True; Encrypt=False"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

but i cannot find my connectionstring. in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings i have only one, strange string, probably from machime.config.

the same App.config works fine with console application in solution. What is wrong with that? problem appears only in tests, (i tried Nunit and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTool and resoult is the same).